# Problem with toggling display-type HTML JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem toggling between display: none; & display: block;

Here is the element i want to toggle:

```
.dd-content #myLinks{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JS:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsById("myLinks");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>
```

Calling on that function:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">Link</a>
```

What happens now is that the element is displayed as a block and the Link won't toggle it back...

What am i doing wrong?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kx37dcbv/

Comment: There is no `getElementsById`. It's `getElementById`

Comment: Alright, i changed it back with no result.

Comment: You'll need to post a [mcve] in your question, not on jsFiddle. And just by looking there, what element has the ID of `myLinks`?

Comment: There is no `#myLinks` element in the code shown.  And the code *linked to* is far from a [mcve].  Please update the question to a minimal runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. First, there is no such thing as `getElementsById`, instead, you should be calling `getElementById`.
2. You don't actually have an element in your HTML code with the ID myLinks. In your fiddle, you have this block between lines 208-226:

```html
<section class="p-menu1">
  <nav id="navbar" class="navigation" role="navigation">
     <input id="toggle1" type="checkbox" />
     <label class="hamburger1" for="toggle1">
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="meat"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
     </label>
     <nav class="menu1">
        <div class="dd">
           <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">Link</a>
           <div class="dd-content">
              <p>Hello World!</p>
           </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
  </nav>
</section>
```

When I run the fiddle and click on your 'Link', I get the error `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#283:9'>283:9</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"`. This tells me that your function call to `getElementById` is unable to find an element with that ID.

You need to add an `id="myLinks"` to one of your elements in your HTML. You currently have:

```css
.dd-content #myLinks{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  padding: 12px 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

but this is just defining the styling for those elements, so for your div `<div class="dd-content">` you need to change this to `<div class="dd-content" id="myLinks">` in order for your function to be able to find the element identified by that ID.

Comment: This was already noted in multiple comments. Answering it wasn't necessary

Comment: When shouldn't I comment?
Comments are not recommended for any of the following:

Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);

Besides, I was writing up this response since the first comment, and I do not have the reputation to engage in comments.